# Строковые ресурсы

Tags: android, qt

Как правильно организовать работу с ресурсами в qt? Работая с android'ом, очень удобно использовать xml, при работе с qt многих привычных вкусностей не хватает.

Интересно, как правильно работать с ресурсами при создании интерфейса. В андроиде это максимально прозрачно, например, не нужно в свойствах кнопки писать текст, хватит  просто написать где то в строковых ресурсах

```
<string name="btAdd">Добавить</srting>
```

И при описании интерфейса

```
android:text = "@string/btAdd"
```

Comment: Во-первых, в Qt есть средства для работы с XML. А во-вторых: что именно нужно? В Qt много чего есть.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Для построения GUI из компонентов Qt удобно пользоваться инструментом QtDesigner, который сохраняет описание GUI в текстовом файле с расширение .ui (user interface) в нотации XML. При компиляции проекта uic (user interface compiler) на основе ui-файла генерирует h-файл  в котором описан С++ класс с указанием того, из каких компонентов состоит GUI и какие должны быть у них свойства. Далее разработчик использует сформированный класс из h-файла для реализации функционала GUI.

Работа uic скрыта от пользователя и проходит за кулисам. Однако если есть необходимость можно обойтисть без QtDesigner и uic, а С++ класс с описание графического интерфейса, его компонентов и их свойств писать самостоятельно.

Для внедрения ресурсов (растровых изображений, аудио-файлов и пр) в исполняемый файл приложения с помощью QtDesigner можно сформировать файл ресурсов приложения - текстовый файл в нотации XML с расширением qrc (qt resource collection). При компиляции проекта rcc (resource collection compiler) на основе qrc-файла сгенерирует объектный файл, который будет далее скомпонован вместе с остальными файлами проекта.

Опять же, работа rcc скрыта от разработчика, и при необходимости qrc-файл с описанием  ресурсов можно сформирвоать самостоятельно.